# Can I Submit 2 iOS Apps with the Same Display Name, but Different BundleIDs?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, store

So our iOS app just got rejected from the App Store because we offer a sweepstakes in our US market and our app rating doesn't reflect that our app includes "Gambling and Contests." If we change our rating, our app will no longer be sold in Brazil, South Korea, and the UAE -- per Apple's restrictions. Those are some of our larger markets, so we need the app to be available there -- especially since we comply with local laws by not offering the sweepstakes in those markets.

It seems that the only solution is submitting two versions of the app -- one with the sweepstakes and one without (for Brazil, the UAE, and South Korea only). We'd like the app to have the same display name in every market though. Is this possible? Will the apps be rejected? Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything wrong with the same display name as another app, but I doubt that this would be a problem. However, you can't use the same App Store name as another app (or at least, you couldn't when the App Store first opened; maybe now they've changed the rules on this).

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah I knew that the store names have to be distinct, but the display names are a mystery. Might just have to submit and find out unless someone knows

Comment: I can prove by example that the same display name is not a problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll be fine on the display names. The two versions of [Marvin](http://www.appstafarian.com) have different bundle IDs and are sold as distinct apps, but their display names are both "Marvin".

Comment: You can easily confirm this for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted confirmation before pursuing this as a course of action