# iOS can I Maintain two app versions of the same app at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to maintain 2 application versions of the same application at the same time?

When a device gets too old and won't receive any updates from apple, you will stay stuck on the last version supported by your device. When downloading apps from the app store that require a higher version of iOS, it will automatically download the last compatible version from the app store. this is default behavior as stated: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160089/how-does-ios-appstore-handle-multiple-version-targeting-different-version-of-ios/336985#336985

While we will mostly update our latest version, can we still update the 'legacy' versions of the app for older devices? can we still add features to the old versions (eg iOS <11) while adding the same features in our new app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433118/what-are-the-effects-of-changing-the-bundle-id-app-id-and-app-name-for-an-app-l

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339621/can-i-submit-2-ios-apps-with-the-same-display-name-but-different-bundleids/38339910?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C40.1050#38339910

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two apps simply by giving them two different bundle ids.

But you probably cannot update the "old" app without recompiling it against the current iOS or prevent a modern user from seeing and downloading the "old" app.

To give an example, if your old app was 32 bit only, a 64 bit user cannot download it. But if you update it, you have to make it 64 bit.